# Postman 404 spring rest api

Tags: java, spring-boot

This is my application configuration

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=192.168.56.1
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=test

server.port=8080
spring.application.name=test
server.servlet.context-path=/test
```

This is my controller code:

```
package com.example.crud;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;



@RestController
@RequestMapping("/crud")
public class CrudOperation {

   @GetMapping("/getAll")
   public String getMethod() {      
       return "Get Datas success";
   }

   @PostMapping("/save")
   public String saveMethod() {     
       return "save successfully";
   }

   @PutMapping("/update")
   public String update() {     
    return "Update Data success";
   }

   @DeleteMapping("/remove")
   public String delete() {     
       return "Delete Data success";
   }
}
```

I'm not able to access any of the methods in Postman, I am constantly getting 
404 error or method not found error. 
I tried running the application with only simple returns, but still
I am facing the issue.
What am I doing wrong?
If my question is not explanatory enough do let me know in the comments, don't flag as duplicate.

Comment: post `url` which you are getting after run and url which you are using for accessing this application

Comment: this is my url using in postman localhost:8080/test/crud/save

Comment: `server.servlet.context-path=/test/*` try this

Comment: /test/* shows error while deploying tomcat @v8-E

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
server.servlet.context-path=/test
```

to

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/test
```

Comment: Please include more information like the version of spring Boot you're using. Above answer is assuming you're using Spring Boot 2.0